# Is it possible and safe to attach this type of seat to suspension seatpost?

Tags: saddle, compatibility, seatpost

I have a [Merida Crossway 20 bike](https://www.merida-bikes.com/en_int/bikes/trekking-city/trekking/2018/crossway-20-d-9391.html), and want to change its saddle.

Now after buying a new one I am not sure it is even possible to mount it. I had forgotten I have a suspension seatpost, but the new saddle seems to use a different type of attachment.

Is it even possible, and if it is, then is it reasonably safe to attach this type of saddle to a suspension seatpost?

The original seatpost + saddle:

[image: original seatpost]

The new one:

[image: new saddle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the new one has the same kind of saddle rails so you can remove the attachment from it and try the bare saddle rails in the suspension seatpost. It should work!

Undo the two big black nuts and it should all fall off.

Edit (Grigory, Criggie): The extra bits are just the clamp from an older design of seat post. So they’re not needed, but might be useful back on the seat post they came from. The common interface on the saddles is/are the two parallel rails.

Comment: Agree. The new saddle comes with an adapter for a different, older type of seatposts that do not have a clamp head. Unscrewing the bolts and removing everything that they held in place should reveal two steel rails which can then be clamped to the seatpost.

Comment: Might want to add that the "new" saddle's clamp is the old style of postmount.  The original suspension post has a newer style of one-bolt clamp.  And that the standardised saddle interface with the bike is the rails not the top of the post.